# No Action showing button clicked in MS Access Even NO any Error showing

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I have problem in ms access vb code when click the button but no response showing even error not display
Just writing simple code 
like

```
Private Sub Command977_Click()
    mgbo "Help me" 
End Sub
```

In above code I write mgbo this error but no any action or error displayed

Comment: `mgbo`? did you mean `msgbox("Help me")` Please copy and paste the code you have. You're also stating vb and posting this in vba. Please note there IS a difference between vba, vbs and vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the Click `Event procedure` on the button's property sheet in design view. Sometimes if you leave this blank, the code will not run at all.

Then your code should be:

`MsgBox ("Help me")`